# Illegal string offset 'Name' Error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to access the name field in the database through this code. But everytime it gives me "Illegal string offset error". I don't know the correct syntax needed inside second bracket of product_array.

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY Product_Id ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
$product_array = (array) $result->fetch_assoc();
mysqli_close($con);


if (!empty($product_array)) { 
    foreach($product_array as $key=>$value){

      echo $product_array[$key]['Name'];
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch_assoc()` only fetches one row - iterating this row gives you column values (single string, number, ...). And you try to access `Name` index on such value, which leads to error.

You need to use `$product_array = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` to get iterate all results.

Also instead of `$product_array[$key]['Name']` you can use `$value['Name']`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed!! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

[mysqli::fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) does not return a multi dimensional array rather a 2d row from the database (only one), so, if you have the following fields / data for example;

```
name abc
date 01-01-2018
```

Using a query and fecth_assoc will return an array such as;

```
[ 'name' => 'abc', 'date' => '01-01-2018' ]
```

So, using foreach, you can do the following;

```
foreach ($product_array as $key => $value)
{
    // Example printing; name = abc
    echo "{$key} = {$value}";

    // Example prining; abc
    echo $product_array[$key];
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes it worked. But i needed to iterate through all the values and my purpose got fulfilled by fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); It fetches whole multi D array. Wonderful